# How can I set click function false when there is a progress dialog box?

Tags: android, progressdialog

How can I set click function false when there is a progress dialog box?

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "click function false", you want the user to not be able to close it by clicking?

Comment: what do you mean by click function? do you want to disable users cancelling the progress dialog...please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want you users to cancel the dialog box

just add this to your code

```
pb.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

pDialog.setCancellable (false);
this will not cancel the dialogbox if user touches anywhere on the screen or presses the back button.